# How do I clone a repo from Source Repositories to Compute Engine to pull it manually when needed

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-iam, google-source-repositories

On my local macOS the following command worked fine:

```
$ gcloud source repos clone myrepo --project=myproject
```

(though I'm not sure it worked not because previously I followed the `~/.gitcookies` procedure)

But when I do this on CE:

```
$ gcloud source repos clone myrepo --project=myproject
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

$ gcloud source repos list
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.list) User [<digits>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access project [<myproject>] (or it may not exist): Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

$ gcloud auth list
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       <digits>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

In IAM tab I see this service account has the "Editor access to all resources" but it does not help. Even if I add roles Source Repository Read+Write.

UPD: also I can't find the `.clone` role in Roles tab:

[image]

```
$ gcloud help source repos

COMMANDS
    COMMAND is one of the following:

     clone
        Clone a cloud source repository.
     create
        Create a cloud source repository.
     delete
        Delete a cloud source repository.
     describe
        Describe a cloud source repository.
     get-iam-policy
        Get the IAM policy for the named cloud source repository.
     list
        List the repositories the currently active project.
     set-iam-policy
        Set the IAM policy for the named repository.
```

But it is probably included in `.get` and so `Reader` that I already tried:

[image]

UPD2: `sudo /usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components update` did not help.

The only two options I imagine right now are either edit the

[image]

(it is the only thing I've found in Internet that seems to be a solution but that blog post is written in some eastern language so I'm not sure) but it would need the VM stop that is not acceptable.

Or forge an another service account but I'm not sure that switching it in `gcloud` CLI won't break other applications running on that machine. Or maybe I can use it only once when cloning the repo and it will stick with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `Full Access to All Cloud APIs` from instance settings. You will need to stop the VM though first. Just click on the instance name, press Stop, then wait and once it's stopped, press Edit and check the appropriate settings for API Access. Then Start the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the service account of the Google Compute Engine instance, as you can read here[1] you need to grant Access scopes to Cloud Source Repositories to Full or Read/Write. To do that you must stop the instance.

If you do not want to stop the instance, you can create a new Service Account and use the following command to activate the service account:

$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=[KEY.JSON]

and this one to start using the new service account with the gcloud tool:

$ gcloud init

If you use the role editor in this new service account, there is a known issue as the role editor does not have the source.repos.create permission.

$ gcloud iam roles describe roles/editor | grep "source.repos"

- source.repos.get
- source.repos.getIamPolicy
- source.repos.list
- source.repos.update

As a workarround, in order to create a Cloud Source Repositories you would need to have the role: "roles/source.admin" as you can read here [2]: "Provides permissions to create, update, delete, list, clone, fetch, and browse repositories. Also provides permissions to read and change IAM policies."

Here[3] you can keep track of the status of this issue but keep in mind that there is no ETA nor guaranty that will be fixed.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam

[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#source_repository_roles

[3] https://issuetracker.google.com/80329938

Comment: I don't create, I clone.

Comment: In order to clone a repository you must create a new one.